what would happen to a transaction only has base fee without tip
When sending a transaction to Ethereum network, the total gas you pay is divided into two components: the base fee and the priority fee (tip). A transaction that only pays the base fee is technically valid but unlikely to be included because it offers no incentive to the validators to choose it over any other transaction.
My question is if there is a such transaction which only include base fee, will it get stuck on the network forever? or would it be expired?
